# CRM 2011 Online - Infinite Loop Error In Plugin - Can't Find It

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using the following plugin which executes on update of an opportunity:

```
public class PreOpportunityWin : Plugin
{
    public PreOpportunityWin() : base(typeof(PreOpportunityWin))
    {
        base.RegisteredEvents.Add(
        new Tuple<int, string, string, Action<LocalPluginContext>>(20, "Update", "opportunity", new Action<LocalPluginContext>(ExecuteAutonumber)));
    }

    protected void ExecuteAutonumber(LocalPluginContext localContext)
    {
        Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext context = (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext)localContext.PluginExecutionContext;
        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            //Organization Service
            IOrganizationService service = localContext.OrganizationService;
            //Tracing Service
            ITracingService trace = (ITracingService)localContext.TracingService;

            Entity Target = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
            var entity = service.Retrieve(
            Target.LogicalName, Target.Id, new ColumnSet(true));
            var entityStatusCode = (OptionSetValue)entity.Attributes["statuscode"];
            if (entityStatusCode.Value == 3)
            {
                //Code to execute if opportunity won
                trace.Trace("In the execute block...");

                //Depending on the retrieved name, generate the appropriate fetch xml
                string fetchXml = null;
                fetchXml = @"<fetch mapping='logical'> 
                <entity name='my_autonumber'><all-attributes/>
                <filter type=""and"">
                <condition attribute=""my_autonumberentity"" operator=""eq"" value=""opportunity"" />
                <condition attribute=""my_name"" operator=""eq"" value=""The Autonumber Record"" />
                </filter></entity></fetch>";

                try
                {
                    //Fetch the approiate autonumber record
                    EntityCollection result = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchXml));
                    string nextIncrementNumber = string.Empty;
                    if (result.Entities.Count == 1)
                    {
                        Entity autoNumber = result.Entities[0];

                        //Lock the autonumber enity
                        lock (autoNumber)
                        {
                            if (!autoNumber.Attributes.Contains("my_counter"))
                                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("my_counter must contain a value");
                            if (!autoNumber.Attributes.Contains("my_incrementunit"))
                                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("my_IncrementUnit must contain a value");
                            int counter = Int32.Parse(autoNumber.Attributes["my_counter"].ToString());
                            int incrementUnit = Int32.Parse(autoNumber.Attributes["my_incrementunit"].ToString());
                            string prefix = autoNumber.Attributes.Contains("my_prefix") ? autoNumber.Attributes["my_prefix"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                            string prefixSeparator = autoNumber.Attributes.Contains("my_prefixseparator") ? autoNumber.Attributes["my_prefixseparator"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                            string suffix = autoNumber.Attributes.Contains("my_suffix") ? autoNumber.Attributes["my_suffix"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                            string suffixseparator = autoNumber.Attributes.Contains("my_suffixseparator") ? autoNumber.Attributes["my_suffixseparator"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                            string numberFormatter = autoNumber.Attributes.Contains("my_numberformatter") ? autoNumber.Attributes["my_numberformatter"].ToString() : string.Empty;

                            string fieldToUpdate;
                            if (autoNumber.Attributes.Contains("my_entityautonumberfield"))
                                fieldToUpdate = autoNumber.Attributes["my_entityautonumberfield"].ToString();
                            else
                                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("my_entityautonumberfield should not be empty");
                            nextIncrementNumber = BuildAutoNumber(entity, prefix, prefixSeparator, suffix, suffixseparator, counter, incrementUnit, numberFormatter, service);

                            //Set project number
                            entity.Attributes["new_projectnumber"] = nextIncrementNumber;
                            autoNumber.Attributes["my_counter"] = counter + incrementUnit;
                            service.Update(autoNumber);
                      }
                  }
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(string.Format("An error occured in Autonumber plugin: {0}", ex.ToString()));
              }
          }
      }
  }

  //This function builds the autonumber itself
  private string BuildAutoNumber(Entity entity, string prefix, string prefixSeparator, string suffix, string suffixSeparator, int counter, int incrementUnit, string numberFormatter, IOrganizationService service)
  {
      bool hasPrefix = false, hasSuffix = false;
  string returnNumber = string.Empty;

      prefix = "P";
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
      {
          hasPrefix = true;
      }
      counter = counter + incrementUnit;
      returnNumber = (hasPrefix ? prefix + prefixSeparator : "") + counter.ToString(numberFormatter) + (hasSuffix ? suffix + suffixSeparator : "");
      return returnNumber;
 }
```

}

This plugin execute on update of an opportunity, but it throws the following error:

> This workflow job was canceled because the workflow that started it
>   included an infinite loop. Correct the workflow logic and try again.

I can't find an infinite loop anywhere, furthermore, I use pretty much the same code on create of an opportunity to append another autonumber in a different field.  The only difference between the 2 plugins is this code that checks for the win state:

```
Entity Target = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
var entity = service.Retrieve(Target.LogicalName, Target.Id, new ColumnSet(true));
var entityStatusCode = (OptionSetValue)entity.Attributes["statuscode"];
if (entityStatusCode.Value == 3)
  //Code to execute if opportunity won
```

Can someone elaborate on this error for me?

Comment: Out of the top of my head (since I'm not diligent enough to go through the code - although I gave a reformatting a whack, but gave up), I wonder if you perhaps do something in the code (update/create) that unintentionally hits back and re-fires the plugin. Are you doing something that can cause re-update? Does it happen every time? You could do shotgun debug and log everything to see where the recurrent call occurs.

Comment: Are there any plug-ins registered on "my_autonumber"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somewhere you have a plug-in that generates a recurring loop you are not breaking out of, see my question about the `my_autonumber` entity.

The value to check is `IPluginExecutionContext.Depth` which tells you how many times you are looping.

After:

`Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext context = (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext)localContext.PluginExecutionContext;`

Insert this line:

`if (context.Depth > 1) return;`

This will terminate processing if the plug-in is executing more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Be ware with using context.Depth.

Using context.Depth will fail your plugin, where you have another plugin which trigger this action in your plugin.

Now the Depth will be 2, but it was because there was another plugin call this plugin.

I am also facing this issue, any other solution apart using Context.Depth?

Comment: Using shared variables. Here's an example how to pass data between plugins. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328579.aspx